# how to use tclap in cmake project

Tags: cmake, cross-platform, autotools, getopt

I'm new to tclap and cmake

1. Why does tclap need to be configured before installation? I though it just consisted of header files?
2. How would I include the tclap library in a cmake project. Can't I just copy the header files into a lib directory or something (and modify CMakeLists as needed)?

Im scratching my head at all this. By the way I found this [library](https://github.com/lantiga/CLILibraries/tree/master/tclap) that includes tclap in it and it looks like the authors are using cmake. Can I just copy the cmake relevant files and modify them slightly, maybe? Am I right in thinking that cmake initiates tclaps own configuration process in this case?

Help me please.

Answer (score 3):

1. It doesn't need to be configured. It is header-only and so nothing needs to be configured or compiled. The configuration is actually just to build some test programs that use tclap, which is not necessary for using tclap itself. Also, it is not necessary to follow the setup in the cmake example that you found. It doesn't initiate tclap's configuration process and it does way too much.
2. Yes, your idea of copying the header files and including them is the simplest way. I suggest downloading and unpacking the latest tclap tarball (latest version is tclap-1.2.1 as of this writing) in the root of your project. If you do that, then add the following to your root CMakeLists.txt, before your build targets:

   ```
   include_directories( BEFORE tclap-1.2.1/include )
   ...
   #add_executable( program_using_tclap ... )
   ```

Then, you can include and make use of tclap in your cpp program, and cmake should be able to find the headers and compile your program for you.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I will do as you suggest. You are my new favorite person of the day. I'd up vote but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: atsui, your suggestion works great for the most part. I'm making an Xcode project though cmake but the resulting project does not have the tclap-1.2.1/include path under "User Header Search Paths". I have added manually but I would prefer if others didn't have to. I've tried writing as such `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( BEFORE ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}tclap-1.2.1/include )` but that did not work either.

Comment: Can you give some more detail about the layout of your project files? I was able to set it up for myself in Xcode just fine with this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7BkiMmXtP1lcE9Rd3VnUjFOWXc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sure. In my root directory I have these folders: tclap-1.2.1, src, and bin. I have CMakeLists.txt files in the root directory and in the src directory only. The one in the src directory only adds the executables. The one in the root directory has the following contents: `CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 3.0 )
PROJECT( project1 CXX )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( BEFORE tclap-1.2.1/include )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src bin )`

Comment: If the answer here is correct, you should mark it as correct.